# PHP: Wordpress enqueue theme last

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am just getting to grips with wordpress and basic PHP.

My understanding is that to add additional stylesheets to wordpress, I must use the following statement within functions.php:

`wp_enqueue_style('stylesheet_name', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/stylesheet_name.css');`

I have since located this within my existing theme and added my custom stylesheet. All is working fine.

However, I would like to be able to ensure that this stylesheet is queued last. I am aware of the `$deps` / `array()` statement. What I don't want to do though is to list all of my stylesheets as this is surely not very efficient.

Is there a way I can target all loaded stylesheets with a statement like just 'all'?

Thanks in advance guys!

Lloyd

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to tell it to load last. But you can specify as dependency the before last's stylesheet. For example, you want to load the CSS files like this (in the same order):

```
a.css
b.css
c.css
d.css
```

You'll need to create manually each referency, but save the name of the styles in an array and add them with a for loop, it'll save you coding time.

```
$styles = array('a','b','c','d');
$dep = false;

foreach ($styles as $style){
   $script_id = $style . '_script';
   wp_enqueue_style($script_id, get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/' . $style . '.css', $dep);
   $dep = $script_id;
}
```

Please don't add it by JS code.